# removing the block quote and text from a post

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This code removes the images from my Wordpress post, and puts just the images in its place

HTML - snippet

```
<?php
  preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
  for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
  echo $images[1][$i];
}
?>
```

This code removes the text from the post and posts just the text. I want this code to take out the 'block quote' text and the regular text seperatly so I can put the block quote on a different part of the page than the regular text.

HTML - snippet

```
<?php
$content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

I have tried including

```
if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))
```

but can't seem to get it to work. I want to seperate the images, block quotes and text from each post so i can putthme in different spots on the page

Comment: Any reason to not just use `str_replace`?  Could use an array of tags not desired.  Or white-list and use strip_tags.

Comment: i've never used that, this was the result of another post and was the most popular answer